# Find vertex/node using Titan or TinkPop Java api

Tags: java, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

I am experimenting Titan Graph Database. I had a little experience of Neo4j. In Neo4j, there is a very convenient api for query a vertex/node with certain label and property value.
In Neo4j:

```
Node node = graph.findNode(label, propertyName, propertyValue);
```

Of course, index is created to speed up this look up process.

In Titan, I create index using

```
TitanGraphIndex personIdIndex = titanManagement.buildIndex("personId", Vertex.class).addKey(personId).indexOnly(personLabel).unique().buildCompositeIndex();
```

Now I want to find/query for vertex with personLabel and specific personId. How can I do it? Is there equivalent Java API in Titan or TinkerPop to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have built your index it will automatically be used whenever you traverse as long as you use the indexed label. In your case when you do this:

```
Vertex v = graph.traversal().V().has("personId", "123").next();
```

It will automatically traverse using the index to speed it up. 
If you try doing this traversal without the label `personId` being indexed then Titan will warn you that it is inefficient.

**Edit:**

Just a quick warning if you are indexing Strings or words then you may want to look at [this](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html) and [this](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/elasticsearch.html). A little extra configuration us required when indexing words and strings. I.e. you need to setup a composite key with an appropriate index backend.

Answer (score 2):

In order to leverage the index, it's important to include the vertex label in your query:

```
g.V().has(label, propertyName, propertyValue)
```

For indexes w/o a label constraint (`indexOnly(label)`), the following query would be sufficient:

```
g.V().has(propertyName, propertyValue)
```